# Is DKIM/ARC working properly on my Mailman server?

Tags: postfix, dkim, opendkim, mailman

I've set up a Mailman 3 server with Postfix. I've configured Postfix to add DKIM headers using OpenDKIM and a test email from that server to a Microsoft-hosted email address suggests that DKIM is OK:

```
Authentication-Results: spf=pass (sender IP is 1.2.3.4)
 smtp.mailfrom=mmserver.org; destination.org; dkim=test (signature was
 verified) header.d=mmserver.org;destination.org; dmarc=bestguesspass
 action=none header.from=mmserver.org;compauth=pass reason=109
```

(Domains & IP address redacted/changed)

With Mailman, ARC is used in addition to DKIM and I'm not sure if things are *still* working correctly. A test email sent to a Mailman list and then delivered to the same Microsoft-hosted email address results in these headers:

```
Received: from AM6EUR05HT027.eop-eur05.prod.protection.outlook.com
 (2603:10a6:10:2b0::12) by DB7P191MB0378.EURP191.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM with HTTPS
 via DU2PR04CA0157.EURPRD04.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM; Tue, 14 Sep 2021 07:13:02 +0000
ARC-Seal: i=2; a=rsa-sha256; s=arcselector9901; d=microsoft.com; cv=fail;
 b=eb5egkxeCkJnvUpwA/HTQ6aYeCJfbfL3yRdCaAhD9aVMwhljOA6V9RhgWVkVHYRpf77BZvw4IztiAU8Y/sUAUAt7s3f77M4qZ37RzOIWktDkKknW8xFxsOQaJIOaxdWjE7L53F51JMmPlOIQ/RgvkIZyiN77GTCCoxhkayzZaL5O8Gc3Rop9kY90sBNRCi/B1DU1keJ45U+KBfnulEWGE3r2DJ9BrfI8WiQCYFIvR1Ryr0wY8uqQiWlitgbfprEl7mkDzR4x/tNUvowVDqltiedfrM3ML7+AHUW4PI2Ih78Uvv6T0+fZHVrRKCOyczU0S9RilRLxMlh+lEtr+Q9GGg==
ARC-Message-Signature: i=2; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=microsoft.com;
 s=arcselector9901; h=From:Date:Subject:Message-ID:Content-Type:MIME-Version;
 bh=jmWFlJwqirfiVtLi98SrRrGA3zfBLMBC8UI7ReTsiOc=;
 b=n07Rdb5JFtRW5a+UmP0zCEJLks5YOE8ZLI6tzNU37BgF8rsqXy2K+Mj5N5742DMymdKnUnYF99nUp79v9BxwQX7EUt7mCXOlzjo//yR8QzV5mhqBroHoisznRxs70HzISZFDCwzMKgL1/BM6jIMVKWry9aTIt2Ii8ofS/Unw7coGBPccNtALvjJ585UUt2cVfIWPjVgt/ZPJ3d/RRsiao5Ot/Myhzyo3rHpl4nZHoxFDeWWK5kZ1Gy+hUxIqZWz9UswzX8K+i9OshilBicia/q/0RHpUCg1vNQsEIQYMRsNTDmvh+moPz2SVDhgLgJ7UOVjSMaO87T2DTacvEykjBg==
ARC-Authentication-Results: i=2; mx.microsoft.com 1; spf=pass (sender ip is
 1.2.3.4) smtp.rcpttodomain=destination.org
 smtp.mailfrom=mmserver.org; dmarc=bestguesspass action=none
 header.from=mmserver.org; dkim=test (signature was verified)
 header.d=mmserver.org; dkim=fail (signature did not verify)
 header.d=sender.org; arc=fail (47)
Received: from AM6EUR05FT022.eop-eur05.prod.protection.outlook.com
 (2a01:111:e400:fc11::4b) by
 AM6EUR05HT027.eop-eur05.prod.protection.outlook.com (2a01:111:e400:fc11::306)
 with Microsoft SMTP Server (version=TLS1_2,
 cipher=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384) id 15.20.4500.18; Tue, 14 Sep
 2021 07:13:02 +0000
Authentication-Results: spf=pass (sender IP is 1.2.3.4)
 smtp.mailfrom=mmserver.org; destination.org; dkim=fail (signature did
 not verify) header.d=sender.org;destination.org; dmarc=bestguesspass action=none
 header.from=mmserver.org;compauth=pass reason=109
Received-SPF: Pass (protection.outlook.com: domain of mmserver.org
 designates 1.2.3.4 as permitted sender) receiver=protection.outlook.com;
 client-ip=1.2.3.4; helo=mmserver.org;
Received: from mmserver.org (1.2.3.4) by
 AM6EUR05FT022.mail.protection.outlook.com (10.233.240.168) with Microsoft
 SMTP Server (version=TLS1_2, cipher=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384) id
 15.20.4500.18 via Frontend Transport; Tue, 14 Sep 2021 07:13:01 +0000
X-IncomingTopHeaderMarker:
 OriginalChecksum:C027C4C73C859E8BC4DD2D6EB0A2AFC55128E8E6AB569058BEFA2927BD59B759;UpperCasedChecksum:69084D51601C2F94765803933A8A1E513A3CE3B72501EEBE615F8404D9524BF9;SizeAsReceived:5583;Count:36
Received: from ip-172-31-73-169.ec2.internal (localhost [127.0.0.1])
    by mmserver.org (Postfix) with ESMTP id 1EB91BDF09
    for <philip@destination.org>; Tue, 14 Sep 2021 07:13:01 +0000 (UTC)
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=simple/simple; d=mmserver.org;
    s=mailman; t=1631603581;
    bh=jmWFlJwqirfiVtLi98SrRrGA3zfBLMBC8UI7ReTsiOc=;
    h=Date:To:Subject:List-Id:List-Archive:List-Help:List-Owner:
     List-Post:List-Subscribe:List-Unsubscribe:From:Reply-To:From;
    b=c1hpMtUIu4xFaJHhKlp9wvMuMchhYHt8jZhx7iR79DwnuFFRd/YbDd7AvspoQ4tkb
     ob4ZZRRsX8P0Aw3w2iOOEGVOu7cuJgeOCs3tyjFDb1yfo3GAsbvKeaRQPblbo6Oaob
     bUuo+5OY825Jdk2FoVAKrxqrkrC4q2OsFoVGFIAc=
ARC-Seal: i=1; cv=none; a=rsa-sha256; d=mmserver.org; s=mailman;
 t=1631603580;
 b=MriwQYAoGLx6qYcQ3jvD1X6WZP2bfE7/esgXKfCV7gSfQcLpbd3iwiJVFBD+4TX3jfTcG
 tGL6iZ69TrW2A4QS9zn7j0WbZh0YuDea6OGe0SLqJz3vVsVQJXmiduZET4LVkZKWVOMsghR
 2Bti7RMvNwok2WQzsKkOf+cXmUFDOcg=
ARC-Message-Signature: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;
 d=mmserver.org; s=mailman; t=1631603580; h=from : sender :
 reply-to : subject : date : message-id : to : cc : mime-version :
 content-type : content-transfer-encoding : content-id :
 content-description : resent-date : resent-from : resent-sender :
 resent-to : resent-cc : resent-message-id : in-reply-to : references :
 list-id : list-help : list-unsubscribe : list-subscribe : list-post :
 list-owner : list-archive;
 bh=3DIn1IpjU5aYg7foYX2PvB0NxFt3Yvxu7ufHWw90s3M=;
 b=fNNEcs1c31725Mfmd4md62MVMIRbGHfnDf3SHY+W5Yz+Cb5RTYJhCpoSA6VpFUSgeGEYT
 DsjJDpwSbXucdbc2ar1s2TcZpshXBtGb7XSxdJy3ZWpGJ+nZdX+OvBTz8OvtggE6W/W/+KH
 41/BqNmfc1MKlWsJH+q0cdwChifyo2I=
ARC-Authentication-Results: i=1; mmserver.org; dkim=pass header.d=sender.org header.i=@sender.org header.a=rsa-sha256
 header.s=google header.b=xCTkYbMD;
  dkim-atps=neutral;
  arc=none;
  dmarc=pass (Used From Domain Record) header.from=sender.org policy.dmarc=none
Authentication-Results-Original: mmserver.org; dkim=pass
 header.d=sender.org header.i=@sender.org header.a=rsa-sha256 header.s=google
 header.b=xCTkYbMD; dkim-atps=neutral; arc=none; dmarc=pass (Used From Domain
 Record) header.from=sender.org policy.dmarc=none
Received: from mail-pl1-f173.google.com (mail-pl1-f173.google.com [209.85.214.173])
    by mmserver.org (Postfix) with ESMTPS id 99732BDF09
    for <test@mmserver.org>; Tue, 14 Sep 2021 07:12:58 +0000 (UTC)
Received: by mail-pl1-f173.google.com with SMTP id n4so7551535plh.9
        for <test@mmserver.org>; Tue, 14 Sep 2021 00:12:58 -0700 (PDT)
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;
        d=sender.org; s=google;
        h=mime-version:from:date:message-id:subject:to;
        bh=3DIn1IpjU5aYg7foYX2PvB0NxFt3Yvxu7ufHWw90s3M=;
        b=xCTkYbMDUx+tagAdAlyZE+awc/wc1iCI/PWp0jeuJFDM23WMTGo24PJjUFfCV4DH5G
         fKko+n5wov5IKcBpjLvcmg2OGuOQPGAl1ATWtCbl+SgZD4LBWftNLVz3XxJq2IDxb3me
         WF+IHsh3nunXExR17sEQx12pbXPhGmmy3G8We7jrZOLVfX0oRZ8Y6QiY1ACetrQ/FlyZ
         /T4axvHlXsiceP6rr6HwvHdj8XN2NbjkXZF265tfc/l2EdVXyTJlnhxxuxXFGTcBIPN1
         OZadmYo5Q8VCsg78leQDp8eBAATL9JwUmFUDhL2U8KCWKXCCQJ4qVKReEqJB4PK5l5hZ
         4nmg==
X-Google-DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;
        d=1e100.net; s=20210112;
        h=x-gm-message-state:mime-version:from:date:message-id:subject:to;
        bh=3DIn1IpjU5aYg7foYX2PvB0NxFt3Yvxu7ufHWw90s3M=;
        b=4mwQclptSSJQVxNaNlxhXDyNREM5qDVMMr8a2AvZFBoVQ6k8z1B8bMkEZB5I32NRnR
         BNTQUy7XQ2rVx171IgoTC24RPcQvWAd0Eg9+1On7vaMG5bIsY90ED1oavJA5NQ2KVXXn
         vVLr7JcKg0fsuk/xoy9bzRCZ5D5nYGYE6dCPb20iTTInM2QaXQgpoCElv0PQ7N3lvLeL
         KXqrhDc9bMVqbYNmu7rIkdAI+N6iY0IB+mMF16GTSM6RlMOuthl1jEQP4QK/7ShupDIM
         DFWC4U1vdK0+LA5Ep0ajUzgRLAK0k6GqBa+MlOsTxaYCHfruFzVGMYLu+BGhvlK+auc0
         J/SA==
X-Gm-Message-State: AOAM530xf2FH9mmbMhx3lhbVy3KOURBUXCxFSudsrgoQ/IHguihpAlkq
    fdjxxPp3FZqmjlPEPCHf6YHBtWkKPAk7jmICOiu0mHBYPA28SvgG
X-Google-Smtp-Source: ABdhPJx9DHXrQn1DY+0svX/d2C3cT/h78ckSVX6QV//8wP5/4oBzLKHy5TqrppqktHiH0uZ4L+MDNmPNm1KPNNzet1s=
X-Received: by 2002:a17:90a:f192:: with SMTP id bv18mr472417pjb.134.1631603577579;
 Tue, 14 Sep 2021 00:12:57 -0700 (PDT)
Date: Tue, 14 Sep 2021 08:12:48 +0100
Message-ID: <CAKTSSTiPRjknheqN7QbvEZAzscCyRePz4JvQB1fDa39xuShMSA@mail.gmail.com>
To: test@mmserver.org
Message-ID-Hash: ORMUWLHDNPOVZ24JYJ3PMESIUSRL7XCC
X-Message-ID-Hash: ORMUWLHDNPOVZ24JYJ3PMESIUSRL7XCC
X-MailFrom: philip.colmer@sender.org
X-Mailman-Rule-Misses: dmarc-mitigation; no-senders; approved; emergency; loop; banned-address; member-moderation; nonmember-moderation; administrivia; implicit-dest; max-recipients; max-size; news-moderation; no-subject; digests; suspicious-header
X-Mailman-Version: 3.3.4
Precedence: list
Subject: [Test] How does your garden grow?
List-Id: <test.mmserver.org>
List-Help: <mailto:test-request@mmserver.org?subject=help>
List-Owner: <mailto:test-owner@mmserver.org>
List-Post: <mailto:test@mmserver.org>
List-Subscribe: <mailto:test-join@mmserver.org>
List-Unsubscribe: <mailto:test-leave@mmserver.org>
From: Philip Colmer via Test <test@mmserver.org>
Reply-To: Philip Colmer <philip.colmer@sender.org>
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="us-ascii"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
X-IncomingHeaderCount: 36
Return-Path: test-bounces+philip=destination.org@mmserver.org
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-ExpirationStartTime: 14 Sep 2021 07:13:01.9563
 (UTC)
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-ExpirationStartTimeReason: OriginalSubmit
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-ExpirationInterval: 1:00:00:00.0000000
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-ExpirationIntervalReason: OriginalSubmit
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-Network-Message-Id:
 8da823d6-328d-433c-6822-08d9774f16e0
X-EOPAttributedMessage: 0
X-EOPTenantAttributedMessage: 84df9e7f-e9f6-40af-b435-aaaaaaaaaaaa:0
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-MessageDirectionality: Incoming
X-MS-PublicTrafficType: Email
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthSource:
 AM6EUR05FT022.eop-eur05.prod.protection.outlook.com
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthAs: Anonymous
X-MS-UserLastLogonTime: 9/14/2021 7:12:57 AM
X-MS-Office365-Filtering-Correlation-Id: 8da823d6-328d-433c-6822-08d9774f16e0
X-MS-TrafficTypeDiagnostic: AM6EUR05HT027:
X-MS-Exchange-EOPDirect: true
X-Sender-IP: 1.2.3.4
X-SID-PRA: TEST@mmserver.org
X-SID-Result: PASS
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-PCL: 2
X-MS-Exchange-AtpMessageProperties: SA|SL
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-SCL: 0
X-Microsoft-Antispam: BCL:0;
X-OriginatorOrg: outlook.com
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-OriginalArrivalTime: 14 Sep 2021 07:13:01.8683
 (UTC)
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-Network-Message-Id: 8da823d6-328d-433c-6822-08d9774f16e0
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-Id: 84df9e7f-e9f6-40af-b435-aaaaaaaaaaaa
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-AuthSource:
 AM6EUR05FT022.eop-eur05.prod.protection.outlook.com
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-AuthAs: Anonymous
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-FromEntityHeader: Internet
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-RMS-PersistedConsumerOrg:
 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
X-MS-Exchange-Transport-CrossTenantHeadersStamped: AM6EUR05HT027
X-MS-Exchange-Transport-EndToEndLatency: 00:00:00.9874238
X-MS-Exchange-Processed-By-BccFoldering: 15.20.4500.018
X-Microsoft-Antispam-Mailbox-Delivery:
    abwl:0;wl:0;pcwl:0;kl:0;iwl:0;ijl:0;dwl:0;dkl:0;rwl:0;ucf:0;jmr:0;ex:0;auth:1;dest:I;ENG:(5062000283)(90000117)(91040095)(91044021)(91045095)(9050020)(9060116)(9100336)(5061607266)(5061608174)(4900116)(2008001114)(2008000189)(4920091)(6250099)(4950132)(4990091);
X-Message-Info:
    5vMbyqxGkdefRiIkrqg4ZwpGLfyUyJn4v5cLoN5lKwXdusI/i41s1qBGsktqj/swtQInJ01+vhFDsyZNXWXqrj0a99+1or22N3ukmdiSyb1k1ptz10WM/SSCU9mbDX6xYzh1iipr2J9mGgoqib5s1JOfhLrVHogoibBIRTGVaeukc7ecTQyRj4ux3Nwhmt43YYWKeqDG4XgX8obB2vWFqw==
X-Message-Delivery: Vj0xLjE7dXM9MDtsPTA7YT0wO0Q9MTtHRD0yO1NDTD0tMQ==
X-Microsoft-Antispam-Message-Info:
    =?us-ascii?Q?g0Qa183Yfq7SY4i7wKx716EEM1w+IyCwbRK9aOFS0Ep+WmpHoOy5Mq966RH7?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?9RGYWFY1IfZ2w0/ytYgAPbgXGg5okckkKLB3ZKlxNlnfDk/nySn8C6RlCu/t?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?V6A+kb6zzWQI+PvdwNu1jQew8agjL2Yg8SHSrZJisyu/i5B9cTNrHZTYvX3w?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?uz9Ozh1NW9HkJTxWtXYTCKtLieIWGobTQbm8fYLF56QCyRJ/sMYWuCwqS1F5?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?fnsXlwODnSocVPvp2o3SeQXP8xsZ4zT+BX2QRVQG8h7+1iXk9YMNvPkLmIZN?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?QFZbPndZUuQs9NLggIjHnNkIMBboM+J9C8LBw3V3hm6F1zpHHj8hCGRUSZ4l?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?XaKZRgKU2G/TSyG1leZYA500/bUGq+1WIcmDt0r7CUc6FLut3toh/roeRjtW?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?ZmtOwwUTonV4L5h0L7xU4Z+R9EWr9lltQVzXTicTgtrkK32cekaHBL75q+h+?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?siwo3kUnFJbpeF73jSYExCXeez/DBILLqfGstDQ0bujnK19S7U1RNai1MzOn?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?BRevh9pn+DzRqiJl3fvMCl9IuARFm9ikxvZXVROuX2hHAliC9rv8OeBH2UWF?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?Agdb/l+3/X4/GoDLMSDfZevqRjk+T+lke7rNTQoq430CpI85izZCSu3OU+es?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?DNlxMI3x4G7eHZAHTaC6h8AN/1KDymKmLF2Cim/wyVdoZJW6i9GRBJ4eMAB4?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?iGGErK5+hPfBPYPpcbFHouJspu6q51ijmY3u/tSivCdveYGEboYopxTLn+qq?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?TKs7XM+U2ZcnV9Y4FzICuhkPzT4KNuIWhu4p+zbaFbtpBVhMHy02mv7pEEgZ?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?dvAKMghz0KxeloCEuV5Wg8Lf9ODixXm6v87r0zayges5sK+kHo8o9TkujXBw?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?slz5LBpRKEM+jpuy6jZLZT2AP0Y+wgmkmGZ+DFZ6+WNR35NWprI/qwAsKwRk?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?ZkPn8fAsYIYDCq4QJWtE9ni4HG2dNgONZ3/bRiQPKyp7eWoqA7bJa06r0fVc?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?treJR24f8ritZD/lmZbsb907n/qQrB1lGGtp/YFv82onwV1gd+398pVU9FM9?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?N19gzh6Z+abRCDRybKg9q00ooajOolfuZrBWGh6Elrqz9mlUE41MH7v/gRfS?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?9zh2D5b1ONLz?=
MIME-Version: 1.0
```

This seems to be suggesting that one DKIM piece passed (signature was verified) but another DKIM piece failed (signature did not verify). Is that why, overall, arc is marked as failed?

I'm struggling to understand where I might have things misconfigured in a way that DKIM isn't consistently working. Any help appreciated :)

Edited to include full headers from the Mailman-generated email.

Also, on a Mailman list, someone has suggested switching from Mailman's ARC handler to a milter for Postfix. I've started looking at OpenARC but the documentation is scarce.

Comment: @anx Thank you. Unfortunately, at the moment, I've only got email accounts with Google and Microsoft, and Google's servers are not accepting the email. I will update the post with complete headers.

Comment: Can you send mail from an e-mail address that doesn't sign with DKIM (so that we're left with only the Mailman DKIM signature)? If that passes then, can you confirm that any of these headers aren't modified in transit: `mime-version:from:date:message-id:subject:to`?

Comment: @anx ah ... that may well be where the problem lies. I've got Postfix configured to do the DKIM piece but Mailman is doing the ARC piece. So Mailman does ARC then sends the email out via Postfix which then adds DKIM. I don't think I can get Mailman to add the DKIM headers so that suggests turning OFF ARC in Mailman and getting something like OpenARC to do it instead.

Comment: Hows the relationship between mailman and postfix? milter interface, or bouncing the messages around via SMTP, or ..? Surely there is some way to configure postfix to get the order right.

Answer (score 2):

> Is DKIM/ARC working properly on my Mailman server?

**No**, if the first ARC-Validator (`i=2`) after you (`i=1`) claims that **the chain is broken** (`cv=fail`) then something is not working properly.

Because of the order of your headers, I am almost certain **you are *sealing* before *signing***.

> All message modifications (including adding a DKIM-Signature
> header field(s)) MUST be performed before sealing. --
> [RFC8617: The Authenticated Received Chain (ARC) Protocol](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8617#section-5.1)

Depending which software is involved, and through what interface they are integrated into Postfix (SMTP, milter, filter, policyd, ..) it may be more or less easy to adhere to the demand from the ARC protocol description. This may involve reordering entries in Postfix configuration such as `smtpd_milters`.

I do *not* know whether that alone would solve your problem.

I would still recommend letting some non-Microsoft party verify your DKIM and ARC seal. There are authentication results mentioned (`dmarc=bestguesspass`, `dkim=test`) which are not unambiguously defined, and I have seen Microsoft deviate from common expectations, even breaking perfectly fine DKIM signatures on receipt, then unsuccessfully verifying them.

Comment: There s one aspect of ARC that is puzzling me and that is *when* the emails get sealed. Is it incoming emails, outgoing emails or both? I've checked RFC8617 and it *seems* to be suggesting incoming but it could be suggesting both. I've switched to Rspamd now for DKIM & ARC handling but I'm struggling to get both working successfully still.

Comment: Microsoft has since [updated their documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/security/office-365-security/anti-spam-message-headers?view=o365-worldwide#authentication-results-message-header-fields) to give a clear definition of the `bestguesspass` result.